# SameSite Update Chrom. Console shows not "lax" for unset samesite values

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, samesite

With the new Chrome Release the following Change will occur:

- Treats cookies as SameSite=Lax by default.
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite

I downloaded the Chrome Beta v.81 which should already use this behaviour.
When I now create e.g test Cookies I still can see the "null" value. Shouldn't this value be replaced with "lax"?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The display here is showing what was explicitly set in the cookie rather than the default behaviour the browser enforces. I think it would be confusing to show `Lax` there, if it wasn't actually present in the cookie. This is similar to `Path` which will show as blank if none is specified, but behave the same as `Path=/`.